# Converter dias em anos usando o lubridate do R

Tags: r, lubridate

Supondo o seguinte dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

```
df<-data.frame(inicio= ymd(19800101), fim=ymd(20200101)) %>% 
  mutate(dif=fim-inicio)

     inicio        fim        dif
1 1980-01-01 2020-01-01 14610 days
```

Como faço para converter esses 14610 dias em anos (ou meses, ou semanas)?

*SEQUENCIA*

```
df %>% 
  mutate(em.anos= time_length(dif, unit = "year"))

  inicio        fim          dif  em.anos
1 1980-01-01 2020-01-01 40.0274 days 0.109589
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função `time_length` com argumento `unit="year"` e  `interval(inicio, fim)` no lugar da subtração.

Ref: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.9/topics/time_length

Comment: Tentei, mas ainda assim não consegui: fiz a sequencia no post original

Comment: Use `interval(inicio, fim)` no lugar da subtração, e aí sim vc usa o `time_length`

Answer (score 2):

Com `difftime`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Em semanas `weeks`:

```
data.frame(inicio= ymd(19800101), fim=ymd(20200101)) %>% 
  mutate(dif = difftime(fim, inicio, units = "weeks"))
```

Em anos (divisão das semanas obtidas pelo número de semanas presentes em um ano `~ 52.25`):

```
data.frame(inicio= ymd(19800101), fim=ymd(20200101)) %>% 
  mutate(dif = difftime(fim, inicio, units = "weeks") / 52.25)
```

Poderia obter também os segundos, minutos, horas e dias ao inserir os parâmetros abaixo no argumento `units`:

```
“secs”, “mins”, “hours”, “days”
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil `em.anos = difftime(fim, inicio)/365.25`?